# How google determines user's operating system?

Tags: google-chrome, user-agent

When downloading Google Chrome, website is able to determine the user's operating system and whether PC is running on 32 bit or 64 bit. How does it do that?

Comment: Browser User Agent

Answer (score 0):

On Google's website providing the installer to download, there's most likely a script that detects the user's OS and "offers" the proper Google Chrome Installer according to the script's results.

For example, open your browser's developer console and type

```
console.log(navigator);
```

then press Enter.

In my case, the output looks like that:

```
5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.62 Safari/537.36
```

Now you could code a script that analyes that output and "offers" you the proper Google Chrome installer according to the user's output.

In my case, the site would "offer" me the Google Chrome Installer for 64 Bit Linux. (Because of the part `(X11; Linux x86_64)`.

I have to admit this answer may not be the best and other, more skilled people could explain it way better, but I guess it answers your question.